# How can $x^0=1$ be proved with a real life experiment?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I saw that $x^0=1$ proof is $\displaystyle x^{a-a} = \frac{x^a}{x^a} = 1.$

However I don't find this a convincing proof.

How can someone prove this without using the fraction above? or, Is that fraction the only proof of $x^0=1$?

Comment: A *real life* experiment? What do you mean?

Comment: It is defined that way.  What you wrote is one reason to define it so.

Comment: How about: a species of bacteria reproduces every 1 hour. So if you start with 1 bacteria, after 1 hour you have 2, after 2 hours you have 4, after 3 hours you have 8, etc. So the population of the bacteria is described by $P(n) = 2^n$, where $n$ is the number of hours that have passed. But then $P(0) = 2^0$ should be the population you started with, which is $1$.

Comment: @VeryForgetfulFunctor A factory production for example.

Comment: @Wolf98 As Ethan Bolker points out in his answer, it would not be possible to *prove* that $x^0=1$ using anything other than a rigorous mathematical argument.

Comment: @user56202 So if i started with 5, it will be 5?

Comment: @Wolf98 If you start with 5 you will have 5, 10, 20, 40, ... so it will be $P(n) = 5 \cdot 2^n$. So $5 \cdot 2^0 = 5$, so still $2^0 = 1$.

Comment: @user56202 You said  "But then P(0)=2^0 should be the population you started with, which is 1"  If i started with 5 it will be 5 because no hour has passed as you said so 5^0=5, i stay with the same quantity. Also i don't see why you add the 2^0.

Comment: @Wolf98 When you start with $1$, the model is $P(n) = 2^n$, so the initial population should be $P(0) = 2^0$. When you start with $5$, the model is $P(n) = 5 \cdot 2^n$ so the initial population should be $5 \cdot 2^0$, not $2^0$. You add the $2^0$ to be consistent with the formula $2^n$.

Comment: @user56202 i give you +1, now i understand it, but What if i start with 5 and every hour it increases 5 times so now i have P(0) = 5^n. If no hour has passed which is n=0, i stay with my 5 bacterias, not 1.

Comment: @Wolf98 If you start with $5$ and it is multiplied by $5$ every hour, then (hour, population) is $(0, 5), (1, 25), (2, 125), ...$ so the model is actually $P(n) = 5 \cdot 5^n$ and $P(0) = 5 \cdot 5^0 = 5$ so still $5^0 = 1$.

Comment: @user56202 Then the key is 5^1=5. Because i also can say 5^0=5, 5^1=25, 5^2=125 etc... So 5^0=1 is the consistency of the predetermined model of exponentiation.

Comment: @Wolf98 That is one way to look at it, but this way ignored the fact that the original definition of exponents  has to do with repeated multiplication. You can define $5^2 = 125$ if you want, but $5^2$ is naturally defined as $5 \cdot 5$ which is $25$.

Comment: *user1015917*'s post is completely bogus; *Ethan* and *Arthur* correctly state that $x^0 = 1$ is a **freely chosen definition**, not something you can prove in the absence of a definition of exponentiation. If you haven't defined exponentiation, there is nothing you can prove about it!

Answer (score 5):

With compound interests, your capital increases by $10\%$ every year.

$$1 \to 1.1\\
2 \to 1.21\\
3 \to 1.331\\
4 \to 1.4641\\
\cdots\\
N\to1.1^N
\cdots$$

Obviously we get a *consistent* definition if

$$0\to1$$

[image]

Comment: Interest_ing answer...

Comment: So if i have 10 apples and every year it increases 10%, Does this mean i have 1 apple at the beginning or 10? It's the same reasoning of your example

Comment: @Wolf98 If you start with 10 apples increasing 10% each year, you would have $10*(1.1)^t$ apples after $t$ years. Once again, if $1.1^0=1$, we have 10 apples at year zero.

Answer (score 5):

You can only prove mathematical statements with arguments that start from mathematical axioms. "Real life" does not enter the picture.

That said, the assertion that for $x>0$
$$
x^0 = 1
$$
is not a theorem, it's a *definition*. Mathematicians could have decided that
$$
x^0 = 17, \text{ or } 0, \text{ or } \ldots
$$
but chose $1$ because it turns out to be the most useful.
You are entitled to an explanation for that choice.

Remember that for ordinary positive integers,
$$
x^m  x^n = x^{m+n}
$$
(true because $x^n$ is defined as the result of multiplying $x$ by itself $n$ times).

That rule for adding exponents is so useful that mathematicians decided to preserve it when extending the meaning of raising $x$ to a power. Then
$$
x^0  x^n= x^{0+n} = x^n . 
$$
The only way that can happen is if you *define* $x^0$ to be $1$.

The same desire to preserve the rule for adding exponents is why
$$
x^{-1} = \frac{1}{x} \text{ and } x^{1/2} = \sqrt{x}.
$$

---

For another good reason to define the product of no numbers as $1$ see [Empty set and empty sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310758/empty-set-and-empty-sum/2310774#2310774)

Comment: @Wolf98 Yes. ${}$

Comment: Great answer! For the sake of pedantry: preserving the rule for *multiplying* exponents imputes the definition of fractional exponents.

Comment: I don’t think that it is arbitrary. This follows from the rules for powers. I don’t see how you can preserve the rules for powers when $x^0\neq 1$. Your answer just states that it is arbitrary but does not explain why it is arbitrary.

Comment: @MachineLearner I state pretty clearly that the definition is in principle arbitrary but that the way its done is the only way that preserves the rule on adding exponents - as your comment says.

Comment: Why should you define something when it follows from other simple statements? Could you give some references that state this as a definition?

Comment: @MachineLearner What simple statements do you think it follows from? The "proof" in the first line of your question assumes you already know $x^{-a} = 1/x^a$, which is a consequence of the definition of $x^0$ as $1$, so that "proof" is circular reasoning. This site expands on my answer: https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/powerof0.html

Comment: We know that $a^n/a^m = a^{n-m}$ and it is clear that $a^n/a^n = 1$, when $a\neq 0$. Hence, we obtain $a^0 = 1$ for $a\neq 0$. It makes sense to define $0^0$ in order to get consistent results. But it does not make sense to define $a^0=1$ for $a\neq 0$, when if follows from simple arithmetic reasoning.

Comment: @MachineLearner You only "know that" from the definition of exponentiation when $n > m$. The whole point is to make sense of it when $n=m$. That does not follow from "simple reasoning" from known things. The definition $a^0 = 1$ makes sense (as you say) but it _is_ a definition, not a consequence.

Comment: The definition of exponentiation also implies it for $n\leq m$.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker Would it be sufficent to define the extension of natural exponentiation to whole numbers with the property $x^nx^m = x^{n+m}$, where $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$? By plugging in $m=0$ it follows that $x^0 = 1$ for $x^n \neq 0$. Wouldn't it then make sense to say that $x^0=1$ is a theorem?

Comment: @Ciprum No, it's not a theorem because it does not follow from the fact that exponents add when they are both positive. You can't just "plug in $n=0$". The expression $x^0$ has no meaning until you define it somehow. Defining it to be $1$ (as long as $x \ne 0$) turns out to be the most useful.

Comment: But I did define $x^0$, maybe I wasnt clear enough. I defined it as the value of $f(0)$ where $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the function that satisfies $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$ $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(c) = x^c$ $\forall c \in \mathbb{N}, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}$. So in the argument in my previous comment, just read $x^0$ as f(0).

Comment: @Ciprum We agree that you did define $x^0 = 1$. Then it's not a _theorem_.  Your theorem is that there is a unique way to extend your function $f$ defined on the positive integers to all the integers, preserving the rule for adding exponents. Then you _define_ $f$ on the extended domain in that unique way,

Answer (score 3):

If your notion of exponentiation is ultimately based on repeated multiplication (there are other ways to approach powers, where the answer may differ), then $x^0=1$ cannot be proven. It is *defined* to be such. And your fraction is one of many, many reasons that $1$ is the most reasonable value to give $x^0$, by a wide margin.

Answer (score -1):

Start with the following equation

$$x=a, $$

in which $a>0$ and apply the $n^\text{th}$-root.

$$x^{\frac 1n}=a^ {\frac 1n}$$

If you take the limit $n \to \infty$ you will obtain

$$x^0=1,$$

because the infinith root of a positive number is $1$.